# Bash Scrolling Output Cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, scrolling

My apologies if this has been asked before but I did my best to find it beforehand. I have a bash script like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

<Appropriate variables here>

lftp -c "open -p $port -u $login,$pass sftp://$host; cd $remote;
set mirror:use-pget-n 20; 
mirror --no-empty-dirs --Remove-source-files -L -c -P5 $remote $local"
```

While the script is running it reports its status in one single line (no scrolling) so the message will pop up for a split second before vanishing (pictured below):

[image]

How do I make it report to a new line with every update? I'm using cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving my issue by using [ConsoleZ](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1164928-consolez-better-windows-command-prompt-a-console2-fork/) instead of MinTTY.